# Typescript Generics: How to restrict key of record to be string?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Typescript here complains:

**Implicit conversion of a 'symbol' to a 'string' will fail at runtime. Consider wrapping this expression in 'String(...)'.**

```
type TableProps<Row extends Record<string, unknown>, K extends keyof Row> = {
  rows: Array<Row>,
  ace: K,
}

const data: TableProps<any, string> = {
  rows: [
    { name: 'Ram', age: 2 },
    { name: 'Toy', age: 12 },
  ],
  ace: 'name',
}

const func = <Row extends object, K extends keyof Row>(rows: Row, ace: K) => {
  return `hello-${ace}-ws`;
}
```

Here is the [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgIwDYQAoCcD2YDOAeAJUwHcoIAPYCAOwBMcoCIBjTdWvHYdAS2oHMANFACu1ANbUS1AHzCA0mUo16UcRBCYAZoxIyoAXigBvAFBQoWYjgBcUAILp0cEIT2DzUOMwh35HgF9TU1ZqLihaOGA4O3hkNCxcPDhqEGEuXgF9IzMLK1soAG1PC2MoajgAW18oAHICKtrhOH4agCYoAI8LUvKqmtqYTBAmr1a7AEYOrs8AXW6vHztaiuqm0yCQzDDgKC0xZkMoN1IKKjoGTAQAKxZgBSVz1XVNHSJiGQAKfLt35qWoPIAJSGfS5SwQYAidDUKAAAwAFhAkEhMABaAAkxm8EACaOscIA3BsgA) to play with code.

How do i assure typescript that they key would always be a string?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the generics to constrain `K` by `string` and define `Row` as an object type that's indexed by `K` (like `Record<K, unknown>`). Here's an example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgIwDYQAoCcD2YDOAeAKCigGkoIAPYCAOwBMcodh0BLGgcwBoioAlTAHdyVWg34QAxpnR08JLlACuNANY0hNAHxQAvBOmz5iles1aeO-QG9eWQTgBcUAILp0cEHgGCtAbl44SQhnEgCAXwCCaRpmKDo4YDg9KFtieycoAG1eYmsoGjgAWxCoACI+YrLFOA5SgCYocJ5iPILi0rKYTBBqqFrSgEZG5t4AXRb+4OcywpLqgnCmRNYcADNWCEZ4ZDQsXDxmNk5-AmjMWOAoNZVJFPkRanpGI-ZufiFHsUY+KRk5BTKNQaQTaLQACjsQkyPkmQVKCgIAEo9Do0lB0BBgEp0DQoAADAAWECQSEwAFoACTWeHhckOfERAJAA)

```ts
type TableProps<
  K extends string,
  Row extends Record<K, unknown> = Record<K, unknown>,
> = {
  rows: Array<Row>;
  ace: K;
};

const data = {
  rows: [
    { name: "Ram", age: 2 },
    { name: "Toy", age: 12 },
  ],
  ace: "name",
} satisfies TableProps<string>;

const func = <K extends string, Row extends Record<K, unknown>>(
  rows: Row,
  ace: K,
) => {
  return `hello-${ace}-ws`;
};
```

Comment: To make the autocomplete work the `K` should be `keyof T & string`

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77545921/typescript-generics-how-to-restrict-key-of-record-to-be-string/77545941?noredirect=1#comment136708911_77545941) @wonderflame Can you clarify? There is no `T` generic type parameter in the code in the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `keyof Row & string`. This way the `func` will have the autocomplete for the key

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77545921/typescript-generics-how-to-restrict-key-of-record-to-be-string/77545941?noredirect=1#comment136709013_77545941) @wonderflame Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` property is generically typed to know that its `ace` is going to be a `string`, but your `func` is not. Depending on how broadly you want to change your definitions, you could fix the error message in a few ways. For example, you can just make `func` know that its argument is a string:

```
const func = <Row extends object>(rows: Row, ace: string) => {
  return `hello-${ace}-ws`;
}
func(data.rows, data.ace);
```

But since your `TableProps`'s `Row` type knows it uses `string` as its `Record`'s keys, you could remove the `K` generic type entirely, replacing it with `String`:

```
type TableProps<Row extends Record<string, unknown>> = {
  rows: Array<Row>,
  ace: string,
}
const func2 = (data: TableProps<any>) => {
  return `hello-${data.ace}-ws`;
}
func2(data);
```